# uploading to PyPi returning Invalid URI

Tags: python, github, pip, setuptools, pypi

I'm trying to upload my package to PyPi and keep getting this error:

```
 HTTPError: 400 Client Error: 'github.com/Palashio/Libra' is an invalid value for Home-Page. Error: Invalid URI See https://packaging.python.org/specifications/core-metadata for url: https://test.pypi.org/legacy/
```

I'm using this tutorial: https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/#uploading-your-project-to-pypi

This happens when I run this line:

```
python3 -m twine upload --repository testpypi dist/*
```

and enter __ token __ as the username, and the generated token from the test.pypi.org as the password

This is what my directory contains: build, dist, reponame (with all the package files in it), reponame.eggs-info, LICENSE.txt, README.md, setup.cfg, and setup.py

This is what my setup.py file looks like:

```
import setuptools

with open("README.md", "r") as fh:
    long_description = fh.read()

setuptools.setup(
    name="libradocs", # Replace with your own username
    version="0.0.0",
    author="username-from-test.pypi",
    author_email="author@example.com",
    description="A small example package",
    long_description=long_description,
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    homepage="https://github.com/Palashio/Libra",
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
    classifiers=[
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
        "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
        "Operating System :: OS Independent",
    ],
    python_requires='>=3.6',
)
```

inside of the reponame folder, I have 5 different folders, with different files and function that I want users to be able to use. I have put blank **init**.py files in both the root and in each of the sub-folders within Libra.

Comment: Your error does not report the `https` in the error. Is this correct or did you forget to copy it when you were erasing your identity?

Comment: Yes, I forgot to. I just put in the real information back in.

Comment: Is your repo private? It must be public.

Comment: the link that I included as the homepage= at https://github.com/Palashio/Libra should send you to a public repo.

Comment: It does indeed. Cool library, let me know if the answer helps.

Comment: Thanks! The answers haven't helped so far. I keep getting the same error.

Answer (score 1):

The `homepage` parameter has been deprecated. Replace this with `url` and you should be good. The example in the [docs](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/#uploading-your-project-to-pypi) follows this format as well.

Comment: I just tried that; got the same error. Maybe it's an issue with the placement of the __init__.py files? I've got a main libradocs folder within it another libradocs folder with all of the information I mentioned above. Inside I have a __init__.py file and then 5 folders, each with their own blank __init__.py file.

Comment: @PalashShah Interesting.. No that should not matter. My packages are filled with header files and my actual module is nested. Some repos link to a website as well. Pip does not parse the URL, it is for the users to visit the docs. Can you try lowercasing the whole URL?

Comment: same result. private chat?

Comment: @PalashShah SO advises against PMs. I believe this is just a silly error. I would take a break and come back and check your setup line by line to the docs. Please post your result for future members.

Comment: I just copied the docs and modified the name and url. Don't know what could've gotten wrong.

Comment: Is there a reference for this?

Answer (score 0):

Just got it to work. Make sure your name is the same as the token name in which you create on the test.pypi online site. Also make sure that you're not creating a PyPi package that already exists.